# Show data sorted by parent objects

Tags: php, mysql, parent

i have a problem and don't really know, what to search for to find a solution.

**Description:**

I have a mysql table with the following colums "id", "name", "value", "parent" with "id" as primary key.
"id" is a autincreament number, "name" is the name of the category, "value" is the value of the category and "parent" is the parent name(category) for this row.
How can i show this table in the correct order, means sorted by their parent name.

**example:**

***sql:***

id | name | value | parent

1  | n1   | bla1  |

2  | n2   | bla2  | n3

3  | n3   | bla3  | n1

***html:***

n1 bla1

n3 bla3

n2 bla2

Please help me out with some codesnippet or helpful link...any help apreciated.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort any table using the `ORDER BY` clause in SQL.  Tables have no "correct" order; they're ordered exclusively by that clause, which you must include in *any* query that you expect to produce results sorted a particular way.  In this case you'd write:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table ORDER BY parent;
```

As a side now, you'd get more reliable results by setting `parent` to the `id` of the parent, and not the name, so that if the name ever changes you won't break the parent/child relationship.  You can then use a `JOIN` to figure out the parent's name.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tableName ORDER BY parent, name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select id,name,value,parent from MyTable order by parent asc
```

Will sort in ascending order

```
Select id,name,value,parent from MyTable order by parent desc
```

Will sort in descending order